# org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible vmcid: IBM minor code: E07 from stand-alone app

Tags: java, websphere, rmi, corba, websphere-8

I'm connecting to the WebSphere instance from the stand-alone Java app which is quite trivial:

```
InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();
```

That code was working perfectly in WebSphere 7, but after updating to WebSphere 8.5 I got the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1276)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1457)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1164)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1423)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1886)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1379)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
    at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1441)
    ... 43 more
```

After research, I've fout out that [IBM support page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21614221), which said to go to CSIv2 inbound and outbound settings (by me, Admin Console->Security->GlobalSecurity->RMI/IIOP security) and set the transport to SSL-Supported.

However, it didn't change anything. I've tried to change the 'Cleint certificate authentication' to Never, and Transport to TCP/IP for both CSIv2 inbound and outbound, but still without success. The error persisted until I've turned off 'Enable administrative security', which is not an option, because I need to enable 'Application Security' (the application logic depends of that).

How can I make my code working again? Everything was OK on WebSphere 7.

Comment: I suggest you report the problem to the vendor.

Answer (score 2):

My research on this issue may prove useful to others;

WebSphere 8 changed the default setting of RMI/IIOP SSL security from
   'supported' to 'required'. If you want a secure connection you'll need
   to get the certs from the server and set Java system properties to files that specify the location of the certs;

> ```
> com.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:/opt/IBM/JazzSM/profile/properties/sas.client.props
> com.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=file:/opt/IBM/JazzSM/profile/properties/ssl.client.props
> ```

If this doesn't work, you'll need to start debugging by setting the following System properties;

> ```
> com.ibm.CORBA.Debug=true
> com.ibm.CORBA.CommTrace=true
> com.ibm.CORBA.Debug.Output=/tmp/corba.log
> ```

By studying this log and orb trace logs in the working directory, I found that the client failed to establish an ephemeral TCP connection to the server at "port=0".  No mention of SSL in the logs!  I wrote a small app to test my code running as a java console app and found that the SSL connection was successful and it worked fine.  By diff'ing the logs, I found that only in the good case, the JVM was finding a local file 'orb.properties'.  I then found that in my problem case, my test app was using a different JVM and my real app was using a JVM that had no 'orb.properties'. I could resolve the problem in a number of ways .. e.g. by including an orb.properties in my application and injecting the contents as System properties.

Answer (score 1):

In my case switching CSIV inbound to SSL-Supported from SSL-required **and** restarting the server helped.

Answer (score 0):

The error description

> > org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible vmcid: IBM minor code: E07

is very vague and happens under many, not directly connected circumstances.

In my case it had nothing to do with RMI/IIOP security settings, but it was a **classpath problem**. I was still using old version of `com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient`.

Switching to thinclient 8.5.0, as well as setting the launch JRE to standard (Oracle) JVM has fixed the problem.