# org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible - Between applications

Tags: exception, websphere, messaging, corba

Exception :

when I communicating between the the applications, I am facing the below issue.

I gone through the below links but they are for client lookup applications.

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062079/org-omg-corba-transient-initial-and-forwarded-ior-inaccessible-vmcid-ibm-minor)

I saw this link too but it is not descriptive(ilustrative).
[IBM link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21614221)

FYI : both applications are within same cluster.

Any help will be appreciaterd

```
    Exception in JMSEngine() Constructor 
    javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1553) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1043) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:963) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:615) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161) ~[na:na]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:422) ~[na:1.7.0]



Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1287) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1461) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1175) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1427) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1897) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1383) ~[na:na]
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1550) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Comment: look at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21614668

Comment: and, w/o any code or further problem description, helping here is hard

Comment: the codes are product built, so It's difficult for me to simulate, I'm trying to simulate it. BTW  I have tried  IBM link too.. doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Are all your servers reachable with their hostname and ip address, any changes made in that area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was solved by, adding ssl supported for outbound communications also.

To those who are facing the issue, do the same for both  **inbound communications and outbound communications** as suggested in the [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062079/org-omg-corba-transient-initial-and-forwarded-ior-inaccessible-vmcid-ibm-minor).

Security -> Global security, then go to CSIv2 inbound communications (and outbound communications as well) -> CSIv2 Transport Layer -> Transport, change SSL-Required (the default in V8) to SSL-Supported